# How can I get an aggregated count of rows grouped by two values and enforcing uniqueness on a third in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet which is connected to an external integration that automatically populates rows with new 'events' contained within one of the sheets. I want to create a second sheet that contains formulas which automatically aggregates the counts of these events, with a few caveats. It is probably easiest to explain the problem with a few pictures. Here is what the input sheet data looks like (simplified):

[image: input]

So as you can see, each event row contains a unique event ID, some date fields, a user ID, and a user name. What I ultimately want to do is count how many events were created by each user, each month. So the desired output would look something like this:

[image: output]

I think that maybe I accomplish this with a `COUNTIFS` function somehow? But there is one critical caveat: sometimes the integration that adds rows to the input event list screws up and adds duplicate rows. I show this above in my screenshot where you can see that rows 3 & 4 are identical, both with the same event ID of 126. Is there some way I can make the formula smart enough so that it automatically filters out any accidental duplicates like this?

Comment: I am confused. Your subject reads Excel; your question refers to Google Sheets, and your tags have both. Please pick one or the other. And if sheets, please move this to the appropriate group; if Excel, please remove the sheets tag and clarify your question. And also add the version of Excel you are working with.

Comment: Excel or Google Sheets? What is it? Seems like Google Sheets.

Comment: Does it matter? The formulas will very likely be the same in both...

Comment: If you build an intermediate table with only the unique values of the base data table, then a pivot table would be all you need. Once you understand the intermediate table option, you could probably figure out the formulas you would need to build a new table from the base data table.

Comment: If you wait a little, excel is supposed to come out with `PIVOTBY` and `GROUPBY` which could be the easiest solution. Perhaps sheets already has these formulas...

Comment: @soapergem Yes, it matters. Especially with the advanced functions of Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to work on this, but in terms of readability may be use `GROUPBY()` in `MS365` *(available for `Beta Users` only)* and for `Google-Sheets` use `QUERY()` functions. Formulas shown below are simple and straight forward.

**In Excel:**

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _UniqueRecords, CHOOSECOLS(UNIQUE(EventTable),4,6),
     _Output, GROUPBY(_UniqueRecords,TAKE(_UniqueRecords,,1),COUNTA,,0,-1),
     VSTACK({"Month","User Name","Count"},_Output))
```

---

**Note:** `GROUPBY()` or `PIVOTBY()` functions are presently available in `MS365` **Beta** Versions. Also ensure to convert the range into a `Structured References` aka `Tables` that helps in automatically adjust thus minimizing the need to update the ranges manually in the formulas, as well as ensures to save time, with less risk of errors.

`EventTable` refers to the range `A1:F9`

---

Another alternative approach in `Excel` using `MMULT()` Function:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _UniqueRecords, CHOOSECOLS(UNIQUE(EventTable),4,6),
     _JoinRecords, TAKE(_UniqueRecords,,1)&"|"&TAKE(_UniqueRecords,,-1),
     _Counts, MMULT(N(_JoinRecords=TOROW(_JoinRecords)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(_JoinRecords),,,0)),
     _Output, UNIQUE(HSTACK(_UniqueRecords,_Counts)),
     VSTACK({"Month","User Name","Count"},_Output))
```

---

**Perhaps in Google-Sheets:**

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _UniqueRecords, CHOOSECOLS(UNIQUE(A2:F),4,6),
     QUERY(_UniqueRecords,"Select Col1, Col2, Count(Col1)
                           Where Col1 is not null
                           Group By Col1, Col2
                           Order By Col1 desc
                           Label Col1 'Month', Col2 'User Name', Count(Col1) 'Count'"))
```

---

This can also be accomplished using `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `EventTable`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="EventTable"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Start Time", type date}, {"End Time", type date}, {"Month", type text}, {"User Name", type text}, {"Event ID", Int64.Type}, {"User ID", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Month", "User Name"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"User Name", Order.Ascending}, {"Month", Order.Descending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---